# Junit/PowerMockito : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist.CannotCompileException

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

Getting below exception while running junit test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javassist.CannotCompileException
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDefaultExtraMockTransformers(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:257)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:169)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:96)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:89)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javassist.CannotCompileException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    ... 28 more
```

I have below two classes :

```
public class Employee {

   public static int count() {
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }

}

public class EmployeeService {

   public int getEmployeeCount() {
     return Employee.count();
   }

}
```

I wrote below test class to test the EmployeeService :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class EmployeeServiceTest {

  @Test
  public void testGetEmployeeCount() {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Employee.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Employee.count()).thenReturn(900);

    EmployeeService employeeService = new  EmployeeService();

    Assert.assertEquals(900,employeeService.getEmployeeCount());
  }

}
```

Dependencies used for mockito and power mockito are as follows:

- mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
- powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar
- objenesis-2.1.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar

To resolve the exception I also added javassist-3.12.0.GA-sources.jar to the classpath but it did not help.

But getting exception as shown above. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2):

`javassist-3.12.0.GA-sources.jar` is like to contain sources (java text files), not compiled java class files. Use `jar tf javassist-3.12.0.GA-sources.jar` to investigate and make sure you include a jar containing `.class` files.

Comment: You're welcome! If you'd like to "accept an answer" to indicate that your question is resolved, please click the checkmark to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. [Click here to find out more.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)